# Android: How does the embedded list of trusted Certificate Authorities gets updated?

Tags: android, google-chrome, gmail, certificate, ssl-certificate

How does the embedded list of trusted Certificate Authorities gets updated? Does it come with an Android update? Is there an other update mechanism. Does GMail/Chrome come with an own trusted list?

If not: all rusted root certificates will eventually expire if the device isn't supported by the vendor anymore. Right?